# Git produces "BUG: There are unmerged index entries"

Tags: git, debugging, merge, fatal-error

When doing:

```
git merge some-branch
```

I get

```
BUG: There are unmerged index entries:
BUG: 3 docfatal: Bug in merge-recursive.c
```

Not sure what this means, but it looks like something more unexpected then usually. What am I supposed to do with this? Is there some clean up command that could help me here?

**EDIT**

What is worse, this bug actually spreads along one of the versions of my source. As `some-branch` was originally just my local work, I pushed it onto the remote server. Then cloned a fresh repository and tried to merge the aforementioned branch on this copy and got the same message.

**EDIT 2**

I used GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY=5 and got:

```
$> export GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY=5; git merge origin/funkload 
Merging:
a1ef5a2 Uaktualniony INSTALL.
virtual origin/funkload
found 2 common ancestor(s):
d2eb442 Resources py.
119871b Nowy commit w doc.
  Merging:
  d2eb442 Resources py.
  119871b Nowy commit w doc.
  found 1 common ancestor(s):
  62f4183 Poprawiony bug w obsłudze linków do resources, które są null.
  Removing doc/concept/agreement.lyx
  Removing doc/concept/agreement.pdf
  Removing doc/concept/concept.lyx
  ...
  Removing druglo-doc
  Removing src/db/fixtures/initial.json
  Skipped src/druglo/backend/actions/tests/fight.py (merged same as existing)
  Auto-merging src/druglo/backend/characters/models/behaviours.py
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/druglo/backend/characters/models/behaviours.py
  Auto-merging src/druglo/backend/players/models/players.py
  Auto-merging src/druglo/backend/worlds/resources.py
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/druglo/backend/worlds/resources.py
  Auto-merging src/druglo/common/integrity/webservices/resources.py
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/druglo/common/integrity/webservices/resources.py
  Removing src/druglo/frontend/cityscreen/models.py
  Removing src/druglo/frontend/forms.py
  Removing src/druglo/frontend/mainscreen/models.py
  Removing src/druglo/frontend/models.py
  CONFLICT (directory/file): There is a directory with name doc in Temporary merge branch 1. Adding doc as doc~Temporary merge branch 2
BUG: There are unmerged index entries:
BUG: 3 docfatal: Bug in merge-recursive.c
```

Note: I've recently moved one of my directories into a separate submodule. Now I get a lot of conflicts because of that. It seems the bug is related to that.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Ok. I thought they mentioned 1.7.3.1 fixed that kind of bug, but that doesn't seem to be the case (http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg835756.html)

Comment: Can you try to set `GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY` to 5 as mentioned in http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-merge-segfault-in-1-6-6-and-master-td4427578.html?

Comment: @VonC Thanks, it helped debug the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message was [introduced in January 2010](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-merge-segfault-in-1-6-6-and-master-td4427578.html), and to help debug this case, Junio C. Hamano recommends settings `GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY` to 5:

> We *might* want to suggest the user to set `GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY` to 5 and re-run the merge in the message.
>   At least we will know which part of `process_renames()` or `process_entry()` functions is not correctly handling the unmerged paths, and it might help us diagnosing the issue.

The [OP julkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475763/julkiewicz) reports

```
CONFLICT (directory/file): 
There is a directory with name doc in Temporary merge branch 1. 
Adding doc as doc~Temporary merge branch 2
```

which allowed for isolating the directory causing this error message.

Answer (score 2):

I've just removed the `doc/` (the conflicting folder) in the current checkout and re-run the merge. Got some conflicts but, no bugs this time.

Comment: Excellent. I have posted the link I mentioned in the comment as an answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off rename detection worked for me when I encountered this error.

```
git merge --no-ff -s recursive -X no-renames <branchToMerge>
```

Comment: Adding no-renames gives the error "merge: no-renames - not something we can merge"

Answer (score -1):

Just in case this helps someone, for the the solution was to change the strategy as well:

git merge -s ours

The base branch had diverted way too long ago and a rebase was not possible, so this solved the issue bringing the changes from my branch while keeping what was on the current branch.