# BUG: There are unmerged index entries

Tags: git

I am trying to merge with a branch, and this is the error I'm getting:

```
BUG: There are unmerged index entries:
BUG: 2 src/assets/svg/arrow-black.svg
BUG: merge-recursive.c:429: unmerged index entries in merge-recursive.c
```

I don't really know what else to add. I've been searching, but I saw the exact same explanation on 5 different websites, and it doesn't help

Recreating the branch doesn't help

Comment: Have you tried looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761229/git-produces-bug-there-are-unmerged-index-entries

Comment: Yup. That's the one post all over the internet. But it still doesn't help

Comment: (1 of 2) Interesting.  That's not the only thing I find when searching.  I find one that suggests turning off rename detection (not a fix, but maybe a workaround).  I find one that suggests a bug in older versions of git (what version are you using?).  The thing is, that message indicates an unexpected condition in git - nothing says it's going to be the SAME unexpected condition as someone else.  It's not like a defined error message where "if you do this, you will get this response".  So ...

Comment: (2 of 2) What you need to do is, take this issue to the git community.  This page talks about how to report git bugs: https://git-scm.com/community ; while I'm sure many of us are curious what's going on, the fact is SO is a general-purpose programming Q&A site, not tech support for git (or any other tool)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you [Mark Adelsberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7050130/mark-adelsberger) for the suggestion.

This is the answer that helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013497/7055769

I fixed it by running

```
git merge -s resolve branch_A
```

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, `branch_A` Here means the branch you are pulling from or the one you want to merge with.